# mongodb insert() always successful

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have written the following mongoose schema for my collection. However the mongoose schema doesn't seem to be executing strict check at the data types of the objects and items being inserted in a document. ForExample: if I change

**"activity_performed":true**

to

**"activity_performed":"adsfsadf"**

The mongodb doesn't give any error while inserting the data. What am I doing wrong and how can I enforce mongoose and mongodb to practice strict type checking while inserting the data.

```
function initSchema() {
    activitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        observationNumber : Number,
        observation_data : [{
            child_id : Number,
            child_observation_data : [{
                activity_performed: Boolean,
                observation_date: String,
                teacher_id: Number
            }]
        }]
    });
}

function insertData() {
    var activityModelObject = new ActivityModel();
    activityModelObject.observationNumber = 1593570;
    activityModelObject.observation_data = {"child_id" : 236, child_observation_data:{"activity_performed":"adsfsadf", "observation_date": "16May2016", "teacher_id":789}};

    activityModelObject.save(function(err, savedObject) {

        if(err) {
            console.error("error in saving to mongodb", err);
            return;
        }

        console.log("succesffully saveed the data: ", savedObject);
    });
}
```

Log:

```
successfully saved the data:  { observation_data: 
   [ { child_observation_data: [Object],
       _id: 57d07545b839132412da0755,
       child_id: 236 } ],
  _id: 57d07545b839132412da0754,
  observationNumber: 1593570,
  __v: 0 }
```

**This should have failed! But for some reason mongodb reports it successful**

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is not complete. I am guessing you have not register the schema with mongoose. So, mongoose does not even aware there is any rule you want to enforce. Also notice that you need to initialize `new mongoose.Schema()`

```
activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        observationNumber : Number,
        observation_data : [{
            child_id : Number,
            child_observation_data : [{
                activity_performed: Boolean,
                observation_date: String,
                teacher_id: Number
            }]
        }]
    });

//registering schema to Activity_Model
var Activity = mongoose.model("Activity_Model", activitySchema);

var activityModelObject = new Activity();
```